# Get-ADUser - find both ForeignSecurityPrincipals and users of a subDomain

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We have a (2 way) trust relationship between 2 forests:

1. acme.com
2. someOtherForest.com

We have several subDomains in forest acme.com

1. domain1.acme.com
2. domain2.acme.com

I have (nested) groups in domain1.acme.com that contain both users in domain2.acme.com and foreignSecurityPrincipals from someOtherForest.com.

The server I am connected to uses a DC (dc1) on domain1.acme.com.

I have been using the following script to output all the members from a given group (recursively).  It outputs foreignSecurityPrincipals as well as domain1 users perfectly fine, but errors on members who are from domain2:

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Properties * -Filter * -SearchBase "CN=app-users,OU=app,DC=domain1,DC=acme,DC=com"

Foreach($G In $Groups) {
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember $G -recursive | Get-ADUser -Properties Mail |Select-Object DistinguishedName,sAMAccountName, Mail | 
    Export-CSV -Path C:\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

If I add `-server dc1:3268` (the GC of the DC) to the Get-AdUser section, then domain2 members are output fine, however it errors on foreignSecurityPrincipals.

Is there a way to output both foreignSecurityPrincipals and members from all subDomains of acme.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with using the GC port since that will take care of your forest.

But the problem is still the Foreign Security Principals. The documentation for [`Get-ADGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember#outputs) says that it outputs "principal objects that represent users, computers or groups". So it'll only work for those three types of objects, not Foreign Security Principals.

That of course makes things a little more difficult for two reasons:

1. You don't have the ability to use the `-Recursive` property, so you have to handle that manually.
2. You still have to resolve the Foreign Security Principals.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44147078/1202807) tipped me off that we can use `Get-ADObject` instead.

I was bored, so I wrote this for you. We do have a similar setup of domains here, so I was able to test it. But keep in mind that the domains are hard-coded. It assumes any foreign security principal will be on that one domain and not any other. So make sure you update the domain names (3 places).

It resolves the external accounts by taking the `objectSid` from the Foreign Security Principal, which is actually the SID of the account on the external domain, and using that to look up the user on that domain.

```
function Get-Members {
    param([Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup]$group)
    $members = $group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Members | Get-ADObject -Server dc1:3268 -Properties Mail,SamAccountName,objectSid,ObjectClass
    $returnMembers = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    foreach ($member in $members) {
        if ($member.ObjectClass -eq "ForeignSecurityPrincipal") {
            $returnMembers.Add((Get-ADUser -Server someOtherForest.com $member.objectSid -Properties Mail,SamAccountName)) | Out-Null
        } elseif ($member.ObjectClass -eq "Group") {
            $nestedMembers = (Get-Members ($member | Get-ADGroup -Properties Members))
            if ($nestedMembers) {
                if ($nestedMembers.Count -gt 1) {
                    $returnMembers.AddRange($nestedMembers) | Out-Null
                } else {
                    $returnMembers.Add($nestedMembers) | Out-Null
                }
            }
        } else {
            $returnMembers.Add($member) | Out-Null
        }
    }
    return $returnMembers
}

$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Server dc1:3268 -Properties Members -Filter * -SearchBase "CN=app-users,OU=app,DC=domain1,DC=acme,DC=com"

Foreach($G In $Groups) {
    $members = Get-Members $G |Select-Object DistinguishedName,sAMAccountName, Mail | 
        Export-CSV -Path C:\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: Isn't it odd that foreignsecurityprincipals are resolved perfectly fine if the GC server is not mentioned in the original function?

Comment: It is... although I can't replicate that in our environment. It just tells me "The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist"

Comment: So I replaced the "dc1" with an appropriate DC and someOtherForest.com with both the DC of that forest and DC:3268.  And of course I changed the SearchBase to an appropriate group.... however I can't seem to get any members.... the $members variable is always returned empty.

Comment: I copied your code there... the `$members` variable is actually the result of the `Export-Csv` cmdlet, because you're piping the data into that. That's probably why it's empty. You may want to separate those lines. But you should have something in your CSV file.

Comment: The csv was empty.  That's why I checked that $members.  I'll add some outputs to see why it isn't capturing anything.

Comment: `-SearchBase "CN=app-users,OU=app,DC=domain1,DC=acme,DC=com"` <- is `app-users` a group? If you have a group as the `SearchBase` then that's the only group that will be returned. Maybe that's what you want.

Comment: It must have something to do with `$member.ObjectClass -eq "Group"` because it is not entering the subgroups.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem: I had to add `,ObjectClass` after `objectSid` on the 3rd line in order for $member to have a ObjectClass to check.

Comment: Odd. Maybe it wasn't working as well as I thought when I tried it :) I'll update the code in my answer.

Comment: It still isn't running the recursive call though.  It enters the IF block, but doesn't enter the recursive call `$nestedMembers = (Get-Members ($member | Get-ADGroup))`.   I'm at a loss there.

Comment: Right. I needed to use `-Properties Members` on that call to `Get-ADGroup`. I also realized I wasn't actually using the `$nestedMembers` variable in the `AddRange`. I fixed that.

Comment: It seems to work on small sets, but is slow.  Unbearably slow.  On large sets we are talking hours, if at all, because I haven't been able to sit and wait (large being a hundred users in a few dozen groups).   Also when a group returns a single user, this results in an error.  I think the reason is all the additional AD lookups vs the original queries single lookup.

Comment: Yeah, that's not terribly surprising. These cmdlets kind of hide just how much communication is going on with AD and sometimes it's more than necessary. I updated the function to not convert the users to `ADUser` since they're already `ADObject` and that's good enough. That should help, although I don't know how much. I also fixed the bit about groups with 1 member.

Comment: I ran the script and it is working good.  It took 35 minutes to run.  I'm going to post an answer that only takes 30 seconds to run for the same data.  However, my answer will generate errors, and I'm not positive on it's accuracy, whereas your answer I can attest works fine.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel Luci's answer helped me edit my original script, to create a fast AD query that produces the same result set.
This is working for our setup, but I cannot be sure it would work for every AD setup.
WARNING: Errors that occur are suppressed using the `-erroraction 'silentlycontinue'` option.

This will display all members (domain, subdomain, and trusted Forest domains) of a group (in the server's domain) including nested groups. Each user will only appear once, regardless of how many nested groups they are a member of.

```
$set = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser]'
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Properties * -Filter * -SearchBase "CN=app-users,OU=app,DC=domain1,DC=acme,DC=com"
Foreach($G In $Groups)
{
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember $G -recursive | Get-ADUser -Properties Mail -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'
    $subDomainMembers = Get-ADGroupMember $G -recursive | Get-ADUser -Server dc1:3268 -Properties Mail -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'
    Foreach ($i In $members){
        $set.Add($i)| Out-Null
    }
    Foreach ($i In $subDomainMembers){
        $set.Add($i)| Out-Null
    }
}
$set |Select-Object -Unique DistinguishedName,sAMAccountName, Mail | Export-CSV -Path C:\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```