# Get-ADGroup to retrieve members not returning members in other forest (but does return for different domain/same forest)

Tags: powershell, active-directory, activedirectorymembership

I'm in a multi-domain and multi-forest environment. Forest 1 contains the vast chunk of users and domains - forest 2 contains a single legacy domain, and this setup is causing issues.

```
Get-ADGroup -Identity $_.groupname -Server $_.domainname -Properties members | select members
```

When this is run on groups from either forest, the results ONLY return members that are in the same forest as the group. This is an issue as we have users from forest 1 inside forest 2 groups, and vice-versa. Edit: The users from the other forest are NOT listed as foreign security principals in this output, but I know they are there based on Forefront Identity Manager.

The objective here is to get a full listing of users within groups, regardless of domain or forest, as we need this for an upcoming audit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get-ADUser - find both ForeignSecurityPrincipals and users of a subDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211922/get-aduser-find-both-foreignsecurityprincipals-and-users-of-a-subdomain). You should be seeing Foreign Security Principals as members of those groups. The solution I wrote in the link above should help you resolve those to the actual account names.

Comment: @GabrielLuci The users are not listed as foreign security principals.

Comment: Your `Get-ADGroup` command in your question lists the `distinguishedName` of every member (although another group can be a member too). If you exclude the ones you know are normal users, what do the rest of them look like? What is the format of the `distinguishedName` listed there?